# Dagger2 is not injecting field

Tags: android, dagger-2

I have this module:

```
@Module
public class MainModule {

    private Context context;

    public MainModule(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Dao providesDao() {
        return new Dao();
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    FirstController providesFirstController(Dao dao) {
        return new FirstController(dao);
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    SecondController providesSecondController(Dao dao) {
        return new SecondController(dao);
    }

}
```

and this component:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = MainModule.class)
public interface MainComponent {

    void inject(FirstView view);

    void inject(SecondView view);

}
```

and, finally, the injector class, that is initialized in `App.onCreate()` method:

```
public enum Injector {

    INSTANCE;

    MainComponent mainComponent;

    public void initialize(App app) {
        mainComponent = DaggerMainComponent.builder()
                .mainModule(new MainModule(app))
                .build();
    }

    public MainComponent getMainComponent() {
        return mainComponent;
    }
}
```

In my FirstView and SecondView (that are `Fragment`s), I have this:

```
    @Inject
    FirstController controller; //and SecondController for the second view

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        Injector.INSTANCE.getMainComponent().inject(this);
    }
```

In the first fragment, everything is ok, the controller is injected. But in the second view it is not: just returning `null`.

I have put breakpoints in "provides" module's methods and the `providesFirstController` is executed but not the `providesSecondController`.

What am I doing wrong? I'm new in Dagger2 so any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: where are you calling `initialize(App app)`?

Comment: In `App.onCreate()` method. App is my class that extends Application

Comment: Call `inject()` in the constructor of the fragment

Comment: It doesn't work :(

Comment: Please share your MainModule.java .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! I have change the signature of `inject` methods to:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = MainModule.class)
public interface MainComponent {

    void inject(FirstFragment view);

    void inject(SecondFragment view);

}
```

I forget to say that FirstView and SecondView are `interface`s, not classes. And inject methods need the concrete class.

Answer (score 0):

If those are `Fragments` try moving the code connected with injecting:

```
Injector.INSTANCE.getMainComponent().inject(this);
```

to the `Fragment`'s `public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` method.
If the views are not visible on the screen at the same time (added by `FragmentManager`), then the `SecondView` `onAttach` method may not be called.